# user impersonation using spring security in jhipster generated application

Tags: spring-security, jhipster, impersonation

I have deployed the jhipster app as two node setup. When I login node1
and transfer the asset  to another node 2 with different use role but I don't know password of the node 2 user. The requirement is that admin / super users are able to login as any other user and switch to original user. I have tried with `SwitchUserFilter` using spring security

```java
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, securedEnabled = true)
@Import(SecurityProblemSupport.class)
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private final TokenProvider tokenProvider;

    private final CorsFilter corsFilter;
    private final SecurityProblemSupport problemSupport;


    @Bean
    public SwitchUserFilter switchUserFilter() {
      SwitchUserFilter switchUserFilter = new SwitchUserFilter();
        switchUserFilter.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService());
        switchUserFilter.setSwitchUserUrl("/impersonate");
        switchUserFilter.setSwitchFailureUrl("/switchUser");
        return switchUserFilter;
    }


    public SecurityConfiguration(TokenProvider tokenProvider, CorsFilter corsFilter, SecurityProblemSupport problemSupport) {
        this.tokenProvider = tokenProvider;
        this.corsFilter = corsFilter;
        this.problemSupport = problemSupport;
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**")
            .antMatchers("/swagger-ui/index.html")
            .antMatchers("/test/**");
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // @formatter:off
        http
            .csrf()
            .disable()
            .addFilterBefore(corsFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
            .exceptionHandling()
            .authenticationEntryPoint(problemSupport)
            .accessDeniedHandler(problemSupport)
        .and()
            .headers()
            .frameOptions()
            .disable()
        .and()
            .sessionManagement()
            .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
        .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/api/authenticate").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/api/register").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/api/activate").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/api/account/reset-password/init").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/api/account/reset-password/finish").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/api/**").authenticated()
            .antMatchers("/management/health").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/management/info").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/management/prometheus").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/switchUser").hasAuthority(AuthoritiesConstants.ADMIN)
            .antMatchers("/management/**").hasAuthority(AuthoritiesConstants.ADMIN)
        .and()
            .apply(securityConfigurerAdapter());
        // @formatter:on
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        UserDetails user =
                User.withDefaultPasswordEncoder()
                        .username("user")
                        .password("password")
                        .roles("ROLE_ADMIN")
                        .build();

        UserDetails admin = User.withDefaultPasswordEncoder()
                .username("admin")
                .password("admin")
                .roles("ROLE_ADMIN")
                .build();

        return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(user, admin);
    }
    private JWTConfigurer securityConfigurerAdapter() {
        return new JWTConfigurer(tokenProvider);
    }
}
```

After making `SwitchUserFilter` changes in **SecurityConfiguration.java**, how do I invoke /impersonate url? Should I create rest endpoint in **UserResource.java**?

Comment: Did you solve this problem ?
Do you have an answer for me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58780481/extending-a-jhipster-jwt-monolith-application-to-support-impersonation

Comment: https://medium.com/@erbalvindersingh/using-username-only-for-login-without-password-in-jhipster-social-login-case-2c2c7302e9ee- I have followd this example to authenticate external node using superuser admin.

Comment: you just need add  UserJwtController.java below code